# Jade interpolate bool

Tags: pug, interpolation

From the server im setting a variable `videoControls` which is a bool. In jade I have a video element which needs to read that bool.

```
video(preload="auto", poster="#{thumbUrl}", controls="#{videoControls}")
```

Unfortunately this prints the variable as a string. So `controls="false"` will still display the controls. 
http://jade-lang.com/reference/ Going to the section called 'Boolean Attributes' is the documentation of what im trying to achieve.

How can I pass the variable as a bool, not a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't think you want interpolation here. For example:

```
-var videoControls = false
video(preload='auto', src='x.mp4', controls=videoControls)
```

compiles to:

```
<video preload="auto" src="x.mp4"></video>
```

If you set `videoControls = true` you get:

```
<video preload="auto" src="x.mp4" controls="controls"></video>
```

Which works fine.

Comment: This is correct, but i need that bool to come from the server. I cant statically include true or false...

Comment: Yep, this is just an example so I could demonstrate it without a server. Simply remove the `-var videoControls = false` and it should work the way you want it to. You also don't need to use interpolation for the `thumbUrl` variable (assuming it's a string) - just use the variables directly and you should be all set.